# SQL - Create Columns from JSON Key/Value pairs

Tags: sql, json, t-sql

I am supporting a poorly made webpage that is saving all of the data on screen in one SQL column as a long JSON string.  Like so:

```
 {"companies":[{"__type":"MyReplacementCompany:#LifeEApplication.GAINWeb.Utilities.Classes","data":[]}],"data":[{"Key":"existing_insurance","Value":"false"},{"Key":"replace_existing","Value":"false"}]}
```

It is gross and I am on the middle of redoing this page properly.  However, I need to pull all of the current records into my redesigned database and I am having trouble pulling the values out of this column.

Using [parseJSON](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/), I am able to get the data out of this field and into this:

[image]

I am struggling with getting the data from this approach over to a table like so:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you share the code that you did

Comment: I haven't found anything that works the way that I need it to.  So I unfortunately do not have any code to post.  I have tried a `while` loop through the parsed JSON but I am unsure how to get the looped record into a table format like I need.

Comment: do you want to save the values from json to table?

Comment: @SuvethanNantha Yes.  I would like to create a table from my original post.  Where the `Key` record becomes the column name but the `Value` record becomes the column value.

Comment: Are you also getting a row ID or something equivalent that is common to all the rows of the parsed JSON output that have separate `parent_id` values?

Comment: @rd_nielsen Yes.  I updated the original post to show the `element_id` column.

Comment: The `element_id` is not common to all the rows associated with the same company name, however.  If not in the original data, you might use `row_number() over() as rownum` to assign row numbers before parsing the JSON.  You would need to be able to carry that row number (or other identifier) into the parsed JSON output as an additional column.

Comment: Do you expect a defined object from the Json Key/Pair value?  As in defined property names/types, or will the object change in the future ?

Comment: @FarzanMirheydari The property names and types will be defined.  They will not change.

Comment: @rd_nielsen I'm sorry, I don't understand your question then.  `parent_id` is the common to all rows associated within the same key/value pair.  Is this what you need?

Comment: so let's say class Customer is define in C#, now you are having difficulty converting the JSON string into a Customer class? I'm just trying to better understand the issue.

Comment: What is needed is an identifier that is common to all the parsed data for a single *company*, not to a single key/value pair.

Comment: @FarzanMirheydari I am not worried about C# at all.  This is a JSON object saved in a database.  I am trying to pull out the JSON object and save each of the key/value pairs in a separate column.

Comment: oh, so sorry, I thought that was a c# method. I think I may have a suggestion, I'll post an answer below.

Comment: @FarzanMirheydari Awesome.  I'm excited to see your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following may be what you need.  This specifically creates a table with the output columns, assigns a unique row identifier (`rownum`) to each input row, and then uses that identifier to join together the various attributes that are in separate rows of the JSON parser output.

```
create table compdata (
    company_name varchar(100),
    insured_name varchar(100),
    policy_number varchar(100),
    face_amount money
    );

with parsed_json as (
   select
        row_number() over() as rownum,
        parseJSON(your_json_data_column)
    from
        your_input_table
    )
insert into compdata
    (company_name, insured_name, policy_number, face_amount)
from
    (select rownum, StringValue from parsed_json where parent_id = 1) as company_name
    inner join (select id, StringValue from parsed_json where parent_id = 2) as insured_name
        on insured_name.rownum = company_name.rownum
    inner join (select rownum, StringValue from parsed_json where parent_id = 3) as policy_number
        on policy_number.rownum = company_name.rownum
    inner join (select rownum, StringValue from parsed_json where parent_id = 4) as face_amount
        on face_amount.rownum = company_name.rownum
    ;
```

Comment: Is this syntaxually correct?  I keep getting syntax errors from Line14 and on.